Is such a thing available or doable with Dapper to automatically expand the members of a class
Is there a way to do something like this? Let's say I have two classes:
public class Class_A
{
  public string Name {get;}
  public string Age  {get;}
  public int    Key  {get;}
}
public class Class_B
{
  public string Doors {get;}
  public string Windows  {get;}
  public int    Key  {get;}
}

and then a combined class like this:
public class Class_C
{
  public Class_A CA {get;}
  public Class_B CB {get;}
}

now let's say I am saying
_connection.Query<Class_C>("A SQL that returns results from JOIN of Clas_A and Class_B")

So then it would be able to somehow know what field to map to what.
Because otherwise I have to copy paste the fields of those two classes inside the Class_C again like this:
public class Class_C
{
      public string Name {get;}
      public string Age  {get;}
      public string Doors {get;}
      public string Windows {get;}
}


Not really clear but I think you should look at https://www.learndapper.com/dapper-query/selecting-multiple-results

I have one result set : because the SQL is result of JOIN between two tables so some the data for this JOIN come from Table_A which maps to Class_A and some of data comes from Table_B that maps to Class_B : So the final class result is fields from BOTH Class_A and Class_B so I was hoping if I could have a Class_C that intead of copy pasting all the fields in it again I could just refer it to Class_A and Class_B and it would automatically expland the properites of those classes.

How do you relate A and B in the database?

@derloopkat : Just imagine there is some key that they can be joined on in the SQL.  I also added a Key field now to both in my example.

Is the relationship 1-1?

@Steve : In my case, yes it is 1-1 . A LEFT JOIN .  like Table_A a LEFT JOIN Table_B b on a.Key = b.Key 

Following your comments, for removing all redundancy you can add a PropertyB to class A and let Dapper to bind that property to the result of your query.
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public B PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Doors { get; set; }
    public string Windows { get; set; }
    public int Key { get; set; }
}


The query is:
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.[Key] = B.[Key];

Results are fields in this order Name, Age, Key, Doors, Windows, Key.
So if you split by Doors:

The group on the left is A (Name, Age, Key)
The group on the right is B (Doors, Windows, Key).

var results = connection.Query<A, B, A>(
        sql,
        (a, b) =>
        {
            a.PropertyB = b;
            return a;
        },
        splitOn: "Doors")
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

Query<A, B, A> means left is type A, right is type B and the combined result is A generated by the above function.
For more information see documentation Dapper Multi-Mapping Result. There is support for One-To-One mapping and One-to-Many.

Thanks for explanation. But this part " left is type A, right is type B and the combined result is A "  , so do you mean it will put the results in the A class ? but A class doesn't have enough properties to fit all four things from the JOIN.  Did I misunderstand it ?

A has PropertyB . If you put a breakpoint in a.PropertyB = b; you'll see what it's doing. You get the first 3 fields in A and the last 3 fields in A.PropertyB.

In Dapper tutorial they do invoice.InvoiceDetail = invoiceDetail; so you get an invoice with the invoice detail.

Thanks man. I will sit down read the tutorial. No escape from not learning it .

Not tested but I think you could write this:
string cmd = @"select a.Key, a.Name, a.Age, 
                      b.Key, b.Doors, b.Windows 
               from Class_A a INNER JOIN Class_B b on a.Key = b.Key";

var listOfC = connection.Query<Class_A, Class_B, Class_C>(cmd, (a,b) =>
{
    Class_C c = new Class_C();
    c.CA = a;
    c.CB = b;
    return c;
    
}, splitOn:"Key");

If you just want to use a Class_C with all the properties from A and B then it is simply
string cmd = @"select a.Key, a.Name, a.Age, 
                      b.Doors, b.Windows 
               from Class_A a INNER JOIN Class_B b on a.Key = b.Key";

var listOfC = connection.Query<Class_C>(cmd);

and Dapper will just map the fields to the properties of Class_C

Thanks, so Class_C is not really needed. I just came up with Query<Class_C> because the JOIN result has fields available in both of Class_A and Class_B and I couldn't find a way to use connection.Query<T>  syntax for my final result . I could pass connection.Query<dynamic> but that's worse! so I was hoping somehow it could dynamically put the fields of those two classes together

What T will be depends on your use case. I think that in a 1-1 relationship is good to have a class that has all the properties mapping exactly to the fields retrieved by the join.

yes exactly. T is like that Class_C that as you said "has all the properties mapping exactly to the fields retrieved by the join."    BUT to have such a class, I am copy pasting the properties of Class_A and Class_B into Class_C . And I wanted to see if there is a better way than duplicating and copy pasting those properties into Class_C
